# A calculated column on Superset for grouping

Tags: sql, apache-superset

Hi I'm fairly new to SQL and have been looking through our Superset at work and I'm going to do some visualisation work.

I need to do a calculated column for our tiers to combine them but it doesn't seem to be working and I've tried a number of different strings.

This is what I have tried

```
case WHEN 
tier IN (
'Starter', 'Starter Legacy', 'Starter (Trial)', 'Starter free'
) 
THEN Starter
else tier 
END
```

I'm wanting all the starter tiers to be grouped under the one name

Comment: `... then 'starter' else tier end`. You are missing single quotes. Depending on your data, you might be able to shorten to something like `case when upper(tier) like '%STARTER%' then 'Starter' else tier end`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I could have sworn I tried with and without, but it's working now, and yes, great idea, I shall simplify it

Comment: @Isolated I just tried to have multiple groupings under one calculated column. case WHEN 
upper(tier) LIKE (
'STARTER'
) 
THEN 'Starter'

WHEN 
upper(tier) LIKE (
'PRO'
) 
THEN 'Pro'

WHEN 
upper(tier) LIKE (
'ENTERPRISE'
) 

THEN 'Enterprise'
else tier 
END.  and it's only working for the first calculation :/

Comment: When using `LIKE`, you need a percentage sign to wildcard it. Also, remove those parens. `case when upper(tier) like '%STARTER%' then 'Starter' when upper(tier) like '%PRO%' then 'Pro'.....` . Just decide if you need a wildcard at the beginning or not. If not, then it would look like `when upper(tier) like 'STARTER%' then...`

Comment: I'm now looking at producing a pivot table to show combined VPM for each tier. The above is working as only showing the tiers I call, but it lists them all out with the separate monthly VPM amounts per tier. How would I go about them only showing the combination of VPM's across all Starter / Pro / Enterprise tiers? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With the code you provided, you are close to what you want.
You need to masure that the value that you assign to the combined tiers ('Starter') is enclised in single quotes because it is a string.

check that the case of the tier names matches that in your data. I'll suggest you copy them directly into your code.

```
CASE
 WHEN tier IN ('Starter', 'Starter Legacy', 'Starter (Trial)', 'Starter 
 free' ) THEN 'Starter' -- Enclosed in single quotes
  ELSE tier
  END
```